# `module_init` function refuse to execute as a result of splitting the module into multiple source files

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, module, linux-device-driver

I'm currently working on a kernel module. Here is a minimalistic module that reproduces my problem.

main_module.c:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>


#include "other_functions.h"

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
int major = 0;

struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
};

int __init main_module_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "<main_module> Hello World!\n");
    major = register_chrdev(0, "main_module", &fops);
    test();
    return 0;
}

void __exit main_module_exit(void) {
    unregister_chrdev(major, "main_module");
    printk(KERN_INFO "<main_module> goodbye\n");
}

module_init(main_module_init);
module_exit(main_module_exit);
```

other_functions.c:

```
#include "other_functions.h"

int test(void) {return 0;}
```

other_functions.h:

```
#ifndef OTHER_FUNCTIONS
#define OTHER_FUNCTIONS

#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 

int test(void);

#endif
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += main_module.o

main_module-objs := other_functions.o

default:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

After I compiled the module and loaded it, `dmesg | grep main_module` outputs nothing whereas I was supposed to get `<main_module> Hello World!` as output.

However if I remove the line 4 in `main_module.c`: `#include "other_functions.h`,
and the line 3 in the `Makefile`: `main_module_objs := ...`. The `dmesg | grep main_module` command will give me the requested output after recompiling the module and reloading it.

Could somebody please explain me how to fix that? I really don't manage to understand this behavior. Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 and my kernel version is `3.2.0-37-generic-pae`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going wrong.
The problem was in the Makefile. The object file `main_module.o` was not linked.
So I edited the makefile and that solved the problem:

Makefile:

```
obj-m += target.o # Here I changed the target's name so it's not interfering with any other dependency

target-objs := main_module.o other_functions.o # I added main_module to the dependencies

default:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

Comment: The unwritten rule I have seen is to use dashes for `obj-m`, like `obj-m += main-module.o` and then `main-module-objs := main_module.o other_functions.o`. So it will consume less name space.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: I didn't know about that. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: I tried to do what you told but I got a warning while executing the makefile: `circular dependency dropped`

Comment: Strange, the similar I have seen in *drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/Makefile*.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: this file on my kernel looks like this: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/Makefile?v=3.6 :)

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: I tried your solution on a `3.19.0-31-generic` kernel and it worked fine :) Can't understand why it's not working on `3.2` though..